# Correctly combining javascript with php

Tags: javascript, php

little help here please....I was writing a php script for a message system. comments are displayed in php with the use of **$comments** through a function. I was trying to use a light box in javascript, so that user will have the option to delete each comment. How can I combine the following php script with the javascript code:

```
<?php

$comments .= " <font size='3'>   ?>

<a href = "javascript:void(0)" onclick = "document.getElementById('light').style.display='block';document.getElementById('fade').style.display='block'">**Delete**</a>
    <div id="light" class="white_content">

        <form action="<?php=$_SERVER['PHP_SELF'];?>" method="post">
        <input type="submit" name="submit_1" value="Delete Photo" >
        </form>

    <a href = "javascript:void(0)" onclick = "document.getElementById('light').style.display='none';document.getElementById('fade').style.display='none'"><button>&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;Cancel&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;</button></a></div>
    <div id="fade" class="black_overlay"></div>             




<?php  $comments .= "</font>"; ?>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
<?php
$comments .= <<<EOD
<font size='3'>
<a href="javascript:void(0)" onclick="document.getElementById('light').style.display='block';document.getElementById('fade').style.display='block'">**Delete**</a>
    <div id="light" class="white_content">
        <form action="$_SERVER[PHP_SELF]" method="post">
        <input type="submit" name="submit_1" value="Delete Photo" >
        </form>

        <a href="javascript:void(0)" onclick="document.getElementById('light').style.display='none';document.getElementById('fade').style.display='none'"><button>&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;Cancel&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;</button></a>
    </div>
    <div id="fade" class="black_overlay"></div>             
</font>
EOD;
?>
```

Something like that should work. Remember that the "EOD;" needs to be on it's own, at the very beginning of a line.

See also http://www.php.net/manual/en/language.types.string.php#language.types.string.syntax.heredoc

You're trying to use the "?> html... " construct incorrectly. It doesn't "return" the string, it prints it out directly - it will get sent to the browser whenever the parser passes over it, rather than being added to $comments

Answer (score 1):

There are two syntax errors:

1, You're missing the closing double quotes from line 3:

```
$comments .= " <font size='3'> "
```

2, `<?php=` is invalid and should be used as:

`<?php echo` or `<?=` (shorthand echo statements must be enabled to use `<?=`)

here: `<form action="<?=$_SERVER['PHP_SELF'];?>" method="post">`

If you're looking to make your entire block of code 1 string then i would recommend using a heredoc statement like:

```
<?php

$comments .= <<<EOD
    <font size="3">
        <a href = "javascript:void(0)" onclick = "document.getElementById('light').style.display='block';document.getElementById('fade').style.display='block'">**Delete**</a>
        <div id="light" class="white_content">
            <form action="{$_SERVER['PHP_SELF']}" method="post">
                <input type="submit" name="submit_1" value="Delete Photo" >
            </form>
            <a href = "javascript:void(0)" onclick = "document.getElementById('light').style.display='none';document.getElementById('fade').style.display='none'"><button>&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;Cancel&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;</button></a>
        </div>
        <div id="fade" class="black_overlay"></div>
    </font>
EOD;

?>
```

Comment: did it...still nothing